# INSERT INTO from unrelated tables with additional conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm studying SQL Server now and I have to do a project, but I have a problem that I cannot solve. I have three unrelated tables. These are:

**DimState**

```
id, stateName
1,Alabama
2,Alaska
3,Arizona
...
```

**DimTime** (in these dates events have happened that I'll analyse later)

```
id, fullDate, Year
1,2016-02-11, 2016
2,2016-04-21, 2016
3,2017-01-02, 2017
4,2017-01-03, 2017
...
```

**Population**

```
state, 2016,2017,2018
Alabama, 559330, 567020, 572001
Alaska, 347192, 351932, 349889
Arizona, 452779, 454559, 455419
```

And I created the fourth table for results

**DimStatePopulation**

```
id, StateID, Year, Population
```

And now my question is: how can I insert values into the fourth table from the previous tables? I need the population of each state each year with id of this state and date. The result should look like this:

**DimStatePopulation**

```
id, StateID, Year, Population
1, 1,1, 559330
2, 1,2, 567020
3, 2,1, 347192
4, 2,2, 351932
```

Of course, the solution can be different, I just need to be able to analyze population changes

Comment: You say these tables aren't related, however, `Population` has a column `state` and `DimState` has the ciolumn `stateName`; clearly this is a relationship.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve this in a few ways but here is simple solution:

I've created three tables based on your data:

**DimState**

```
Id  StateName
1   Alabama
2   Alaska
3   Arizona
```

**DimTime**

```
Id  FullDate    Year
1   2016-02-11  2016
2   2016-04-21  2016
3   2017-01-02  2017
4   2017-01-03  2017
```

**Population**

```
State   2016    2017    2018
Alabama 10      20      30
Alaska  15      30      45
Arizona 20      40      60
```

Remove your pivot by using the following code:

```
WITH _Population AS (
SELECT [State], [Year], [Population]
FROM [Population]
UNPIVOT 
    ([Population] FOR [Year] IN 
        ([2016], [2017], [2018])
    ) AS UNPVT
)
```

Thereafter, you could join all the related tables using the relationships you mentioned albeit there are no primary/foreign keys on your Population table.

```
-- INSERT INTO EXISTING_TABLE
SELECT DT.Id, StateName, FullDate, DT.[Year], [Population]
-- INTO #NEW_TABLE
FROM DimState DS 
INNER JOIN DimTime DT ON DT.Id = DS.Id
INNER JOIN _Population P ON P.State = DS.StateName
```

I've commented notes as to how you would insert into an existing table or create a new table as you insert data.

Your entire solution appears as below:

```
WITH _Population AS (
SELECT [State], [Year], [Population]
FROM [Population]
UNPIVOT 
    ([Population] FOR [Year] IN 
        ([2016], [2017], [2018])
    ) AS UNPVT
)

-- INSERT INTO EXISTING_TABLE
SELECT DT.Id, StateName, FullDate, DT.[Year], [Population]
-- INTO #NEW_TABLE
FROM DimState DS 
INNER JOIN DimTime DT ON DT.Id = DS.Id
INNER JOIN _Population P ON P.State = DS.StateName
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it's really helpful. But could you tell me,  if there's any way to add only records from DimTime in which day and month is e.g 12-02? Just to select one population from each year, not from each day

Comment: This can be accomplished with a simple WHERE clause

Answer (score 0):

Although your ER for the above tables is totally wrong or no way related. Still you can try the below

```
      Create table table4 as
      (select s.id, s.statename, t.year, 
       p.population
       From dimstate s left join dimtime t
      On s.id=t.id join
      Dimpopulation p on
      Trunc(s.statename)=trunc(
      p.state) and t.year=p.year)
```

Comment: There is no `CREATE TABLE...AS` in Microsoft SQL Server.